# JPLQuery + QueryDSL for parents where all children have the same attribute = TRUE

Tags: java, jpql, querydsl

I'm having an issue creating a JPQLQuery for all parents whose children have a certain attribute (Boolean active) set to TRUE. All children have to have it set to TRUE, otherwise don't select the parent.

I've found similar issues and answers but none of them written in JPQLQuery and QueryDSL that I need.

Here are my entities (simplified):
Parent entity:

```
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "parent_child",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "child_id")
    )
    private List<Child> children;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(columnDefinition ="country_id")
    private Country country;
```

Child entity:

```
@Table(name = "child")
public class Child {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "active")
    private Boolean active;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "parent_child",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "child_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    )
    private List<Parent> parents;
```

And here's what I've tried but it doesn't work and I'm not very good at writing these so I'm not even sure why it doesn't work:

```
JPAQuery<Parent> jpaQuery = new JPAQuery<>(entityManager);
        QParent qParent = QParent.parent;
        QChild qChild = QChild.child;

Map<Country, List<Parent>> parents = jpaQuery.from(qChild)
                    .join(qChild.parent, qParent)
                    .where((QChild.child.active.isFalse()).count().eq(0L))
                    .transform(GroupBy.groupBy(qParent.country).as(GroupBy.list(qParent)));
```

the error I get for this is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found '=' near line 4, column 52
```

Appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: You can't have aggregate expressions in the where clause (in SQL nor JPQL). You need to use a subquery instead.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, would you be able to give me an example of how to do it? I haven't really worked with QueryDSL much